# django or react ,what should i learn for full stack development?

Tags: django, reactjs

why should i learn django over reactjs for full stack development.Or shouldn't I? I'm just confused . really need the answer . Any good suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: react is front-end, while with Django you can create full-stack apps

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs is for frontend.
Django is a python framework and is suitable for both front end and back end.

Comment: If you are new to programming I would suggest you to learn Flutter for frontend and use Firebase as your backend.